# Use python to open mrc format image

Tags: image

```
import numpy as np
import Image
im=Image.open("C:\Users\jhon\Pictures\newtry\101201x0.mrc",)
newArr = numpy.fromfromstring(im.tostring(),numpy.uint8)
newArr = numpy.reshape(newArr,im.size)`
```

I got this from the interpreter ,if you guys do you have any idea  I am new for python 
thanks

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Pictures\201x0.mrc'
File "C:\Users\jhon\try.py", line 18, in <module>
im=Image.open("C:\Users\xxx\Pictures\newtry\101201x0.mrc")
File "C:\EMAN2\python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1952, in open
fp = __builtin__.open(fp,'rb')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install and use EMAN2, the code for opening a mrc file is quite straightforward:

```
from EMAN2 import *
img = EMData("testOK.mrc", 0)
img.write_image("copy.mrc") #write a copy of the image on the disk

img.read_image("testOK2.mrc", 0)
img.write_image("copy2.mrc")  #write a copy of the image on the disk
```